# Best practice for updating newState via shouldComponentUpdate?

Tags: reactjs

I've created a text input that only updates it's own state when you're typing via onChange, and then works it's way up the parent via onBlurEvent to prevent re-rendering too much of my GUI when a user is typing.

This works, but my drawback is that since the input has it's own state, if the props change because of external forces, and I want update my text input to be those new props, I'm in a bit of a pickle. From what I've been looking up, shouldComponentUpdate can create a fix, and my code works, but just because it works doesn't mean that my implementation is good.

When using react, I understand that we should not update the state by doing:

```
this.state.value = "This is a new value"
```

and instead do:

```
    this.setState({
        value: "This is a new value"
    });
```

But what about directly changing newState which technically isn't "this.state" inside of shouldComponentUpdate?

I have the below logic:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(props, newState) {
    if (...logic 1 ... && props.value != newState.value) {
        //keep newState
        return true;
    }
    else if (...logic 2 ... props.value != newState.value)
    {
        newState.value = props.value; //Right Here
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems just as bad as (if not worse than) setting `this.state` to me. You should only ever be updating your state through `setState`, as you're running the risk of later updates overwriting your changes otherwise.

A much better solution would be to use the [`componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) lifecycle hook - the docs say:

> If you need to update the state in response to prop changes (for example, to reset it), you may compare this.props and nextProps and perform state transitions using this.setState() in this method.

Which sounds exactly like what you're trying to do!

I don't know your logic, so I can't give a full example, but here's a starting point:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (/* your condition */ && nextProps.value != this.state.value) {
        this.setState({
           value: nextProps.value
        });
    }
}
```